# webix no scroll bar in treegrid

Tags: scroll, treeview, visible, webix

As title, no scroll bar even I did the setting below, I tried scroll:"y",scroll:"xy",scroll:true, scrollX:true, scrollY:true, etc. All failed.
I am thinking is it because the view is "treetable".
the code is as below:

```js
let dataTree = function(){
  const  config={
  // container:"testA", //the container is the div Id going to contain the grid, we will addd it @ PlTreeGrid
  view:"treetable",
  //autowidth:true,
  width:'100%',
  //autoheight:true,
  minHeight:530,
  scroll:"xy",
  scroll:"x",
  scroll:"y",
  scrollX:true,
  scrollY:true,
columns:[
{ id:"id", header:"", css:{"text-align":"right"}, width:50, sort:"int"}, //,header:{ height:25 }
{ id:"value", header:"Film title", width:250, 
template:"{common.treetable()} #value#", sort:"string" },
//{ id:"chapter", header:"Mode", sort:"string", template:"#value# <div class='edit'>Del</div>", width:300}//width:200, height:'auto'
      { id:"chapter", header:"Mode", sort:"string", width:'auto',fillspace:true}
],
  onDblClick:{
      "webix_remove_upload":function(ev, id){
              console.log("ev,id");console.log(ev,id)
              //this.remove(id);
      }
  },
data: [
{ "id":"1", "value":"The Shawshank Redemption", "open":true, "data":[
{ "id":"1.1", "value":"Part 1 l A", "chapter":"alpha"},
{ "id":"1.2", "value":"Part 2", "chapter":"beta", "open":true, "data":[
{ "id":"1.2.1", "value":"Part 1", "chapter":"beta-twin"}
]},
{ "id":"1.3", "value":"Part 3", "chapter":"gamma" }
]},
{ "id":"2", "value":"The Godfather", "data":[
{ "id":"2.1", "value":"Part 1", "chapter":"alpha" }
]}
]
  }
   let onItemDblClick = function(id, e, node){
     alert("happy" + id, e, node);
  }
  return <TreeGrid config={config} onItemDblClick={onItemDblClick} />
```

Comment: As per the doc `scroll:"y",scroll:"xy",scroll:true, scrollX:true, scrollY:true` none of these attributes are mentioned. You need to use `scrollTo`. Have a look of http://docs.webix.com/api__refs__ui.treetable.html

Comment: Also Can you create a fiddler for this. \

Answer (score 1):

No problems with the scroll bar.

Your code in snippet : http://webix.com/snippet/78021640
I've just removed any "scroll" attributes, to use the default one.

The scrollbar is only showed when needed. If you use the resizer to reduce the treetable size. The scrollbar will appear when part of content become hidden.